# Share plugins, themes, and multi post in a multidomain network

Tags: plugins, themes, multisite

I have created a network consisting of 3 sites (site1.com, site2.com, site3.com).
Everything works fine, and I can access all three sites fine.

What I need is to be able to share themes, plugins and post to all sites.
I have tried multipost-mu, and ThreeWP Broadcast.
When I create a post I can now choose the other two sites, but the post doesn't show up there.

The way I set up my network is:

1. My host Setup the dns with a wildcard A record, and setup apache by adding ServerAlias *.|DOMAIN| to my httpd.conf
2. I then added the subdomain
3. I Edit the new subdomain:
   Changeg the value of Domain, Siteurl, Home, and Fileupload Url to suit to my new domain (http://www.site1.com)
4. I Edit my wp-config.php: 
   define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com' ); 
   changed it to 
   define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marja,

By default any plugins in the wp-content/plugins directory will be shared across the site. You can **Network Activate** a plugin so it's activated on all sites.

For themes, you will need to **Network Enable** the themes in the network admin panel.

I'm not sure about the posts. That would be a support question for the plugin author that doesn't match the scope of this QA site.

Hope this helps you out.